# solving a combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics

Alex has $N$ dice; each of them has $K$ faces numbered from $1$ to $K$. Now he has arranged the $N$ dice in a line. He can rotate/flip any die if he wants. How many ways he can set the top faces such that the summation of all the top faces equals $S$?

Now if $N, K, S$ are given how can I calculate the total number of ways. Can it be solved with a recursive formula? If so,what is the recursive formula? I need better clarification?

Comment: Does the order matter? For example, if was to get S=4 with 3 6-face dices would 1+1+2 be counted as a different solution as 2+1+1?

Comment: Here order doesn't matter.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive?

Comment: You dont need any recursion, exists a explicit form. You can see it [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'll sketch a pseudocode for you:

```
DEFINE howmany(dices, sum, sides)  
    IF sum < dices OR dices*sides < sum THEN return 0
    //if the sum is too big or too small there is no possibilities  
    IF dices == 1 AND sum <= sides THEN return 1
    //if tehre is only 1 dice and the sum is in the range 1<->K, this is a way
    hm = 0  
    FOR i = 1 TO sides   
        hm = hm + howmany(dices - 1, sum - i, sides) 
        //we substract a die, and substract its value from the sum    
    end FOR  
    return hm  
end DEFINE
```

I hope the comments and the code to be helpful.

If you want a formula, define:
$$f(N,K,S)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
0&\text{ if }S<N\text{ or }S>NK\\
1&\text{ if }N=1\text{ and } 1\leq S\leq K\\
\sum_{j=1}^Kf(N-1,K,S-j)&\text{ otherwise}&\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

The function is well defined because its first argument or the third one become eventually small enough and the recursion stops.

Comment: I need a combinatoral approach recursive formula not programming approach formula